# python pandas - Editing multiple DataFrames with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following 2 lists of 3 dicts and 3 empty DataFrames

```
dict0={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.93}}
dict1={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.85}}
dict2={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.98}}
dicts=[dict0, dict1, dict2]

df0=pd.DataFrame()
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
dfs=[df0, df1, df2]
```

I want to recursively modify the 3 Dataframes within a loop, by using the following line:

```
for df, dikt in zip(dfs, dicts):
    df = df.from_dict(dikt, orient='columns', dtype=None)
```

However, when trying to retrieve for instance 1 of the df outside of the loop, it is still empty

```
print (df0)
```

will return

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

When printing the df from within the for loop, we can see the data is correctly appended though.

How to make the loop so that it is possible to print the 3 dfs with their changes outside of the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your loop, `df` is just a temporary value, not a reference to the corresponding list element. If you want to modify the list while iterating it, you have to reference the list by index. You can do that using Python's enumerate:

```
for i, (df, dikt) in enumerate(zip(dfs, dicts)):
    dfs[i] = df.from_dict(dikt, orient='columns', dtype=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will get it done in place!!!
Please ***note*** the 3 exclamations

***one liner***

```
[dfs[i].set_value(r, c, v)
 for i, dn in enumerate(dicts)
 for r, dr in dn.items()
 for c, v in dr.items()];
```

---

***somewhat more intuitive***

```
for d, df in zip(dicts, dfs):
    temp = pd.DataFrame(d).stack()
    for (r, c), v in temp.iteritems():
        df.set_value(r, c, v)

df0

                     actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00    0.93
```

---

***equivalent alternative***
without the `pd.DataFrame` construction

```
for i, dn in enumerate(dicts):
    for r, dr in dn.items():
        for c, v in dr.items():
            dfs[i].set_value(r, c, v)
```

---

***Why is this different?***
All the other answers, so far, reassign a new dataframe to the requisite position in the list of dataframes.  They clobber the dataframe that was there.  The original dataframe is left empty while a new non-empty one rests in the list.

This solution edits the dataframe in place ensuring the original dataframe is updated with new information.

Per OP:

> However, when trying to retrieve for instance 1 of the df outside of the loop, it is still empty

---

***timing***
It's also considerably faster

[image]

---

***setup***

```
dict0={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.93}}
dict1={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.85}}
dict2={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.98}}
dicts=[dict0, dict1, dict2]

df0=pd.DataFrame()
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
dfs=[df0, df1, df2]
```

Comment: Your three for-loop solution needlessly deconstructs the existing dicts.

Comment: @fuzzyhedge no, it doesn't, I need to get at those keys and values in order to use `set_value`.  Using `set_value` or `pd.DataFrame.at` or `pd.DataFrame.loc` are the only options I could think of to edit dataframe in place.  In order to get at those row, column, value combinations, I had to iterate.  I could have used a dataframe constructor just to iterate through it, but that was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the reference to the df objects, so you can try:

```
for idx, dikt in enumerate(dicts):
    dfs[idx] = dfs[idx].from_dict(dikt, orient='columns', dtype=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an explanation for why that is so. However a workaround is:

```
dict0={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.93}}
dict1={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.85}}
dict2={'actual': {'2013-02-20 13:30:00': 0.98}}
dicts=[dict0, dict1, dict2]

dfs = []

for dikt in dicts:
    df = df.from_dict(dikt, orient='columns', dtype=None)
    dfs.append(df)
```

Now

```
dfs[0]
```

returns

```
                     actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00    0.93
```

Comment: leaving this here but @Blackecho is much better

Answer (score 0):

One liner.

```
>>>df_list = [df.from_dict(dikt, orient='columns', dtype=None) for (df, dikt) in zip(dfs, dicts)]

>>>df_list
[                     actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00    0.93,
                      actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00    0.85, 
                      actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00    0.98]

>>>df_list[0]
                     actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00    0.93
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by putting the dataframes into a dictionary:

```py
dfs = {
    'df0': df0,
    'df1': df1,
    'df2': df2
}
```

And then calling and assigning the contents of the dictionary in the for loop.

```py
for dfname, dikt in zip(dfs.keys(), dicts):
    dfs[dfname] = dfs[dfname].from_dict(dikt, orient='columns', dtype=None)
```

This is useful if you can still want to call the dataframes by their name (instead of an arbitrary index in a list...)

```py
dfs['df0']
```