# Pandas reindex a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series such as follow:

```
indic={'indicator_name': {0: '10-Year Note Auction', 
                         1: '10-Year TIPS Auction', 
                         2: '2-Year Note Auction', 
                         3: '3-Month Bill Auction', 
                         4: '3-Year Note Auction'}}

ind_serie=pd.Series(indic)
```

I would like to reindex it so that the values are also the index (ie : `0: '10-Year Note Auction'` becomes `'10-Year Note Auction': '10-Year Note Auction'`, etc.)

If `ind_serie` was a DataFrame i would use:

```
ind_serie.set_index('indicator_name', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

The reindex function also doesnt seem to work.

```
ind_serie.reindex(index='indicator_name')
```

But what is the correct syntax to use in the case of a Series?

Comment: I think you mean Series.

Comment: @fuzzyhedge : yes...

Answer (score 1):

Reassign the index

```
ind_serie.index = ind_serie.values
```

Comment: @ piRSquared Thx! However i'm wondering why sometimes the index comes out correct and as expected, and sometimes as `(10-Year Note Auction,)` (ie with parenthesis and comma?)

Comment: @jimbasquiat that's because that's what is in the series values.

Comment: might only work if the length of the index and values are equal, otherwise this occurs: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 149 elements, new values have 151 elements`

Answer (score 1):

You have a dict of dicts that creates a Series with one element containing a list of the first dict. That's a different problem.

Below I create what you want starting with a list of the items.

```
s1 = pd.Series(
        ['10-Year TIPS Auction',
         '2-Year Note Auction',
         '3-Month Bill Auction'], name='s1')

s2 = s1.copy(deep=True).rename('s2')
s3 = pd.DataFrame(s1.values, index=s2, columns=['s1'])


s3
                                        s1
s2                                        
10-Year TIPS Auction  10-Year TIPS Auction
2-Year Note Auction    2-Year Note Auction
3-Month Bill Auction  3-Month Bill Auction
```

another way...

```
s3 = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=['s1'])
s3.index = s1.values
s3
                                        s1
10-Year TIPS Auction  10-Year TIPS Auction
2-Year Note Auction    2-Year Note Auction
3-Month Bill Auction  3-Month Bill Auction
```

Comment: @ fuzzyhedge Thx! However i'm wondering why sometimes the index comes out correct and as expected, and sometimes as `(10-Year Note Auction,)` (ie with parenthesis and comma?)

Comment: That could mean it's being treated as its own ndarray of shape (1,). Probably has extra [] around it during import. Similar (and related) issue as the dict of dicts being imported into the Series as one element.

Comment: I suggest going through the [split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) docs.

Comment: Yes the Series is originaly an import from a mySQL database.. How would you go at modifying the index (or the value column) from **its own ndarray of shape (1,)**  to whatever it needs to be so that the parenthesis and commas go away when i use them as index?

Comment: Tough to say. Maybe a string replace with a list comprehension. You should make another question asking that and include more of the input/output.

Comment: Also this recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370695) may be beneficial for the examples of iterating over dicts and dfs.

Answer (score 0):

`ind_serie.index = ind_serie.values` didn't work properly

`ind_serie.to_frame.set_index('indicator_name', drop=False, inplace=True)`
was the way to go eventually