# Overwriting existing dataframe in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transform elements in various data frames (standardize numerical values to be between 0 and 1, one-hot encode categorical variables) but when I try to overwrite the dataframe in a loop it doesn't modify the existing dataframe, only the loop variable. Here is a dummy example:

```
t = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 16).reshape(5, 3))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 16).reshape(5, 3))

for hi in [t, b]:
    hi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30, 45).reshape(5, 3))
```

But when I run this code both t and b have their original values. How can I overwrite the original dataframe (t or b) while in a loop?

The specific problem I'm running into is when trying to use get_dummies function in the loop:

```
hi = pd.get_dummies(hi, columns=['column1'])
```

Comment: You're not reassigning `t` and `b` anywhere?

Comment: You should be using `map()` or `apply()` to update Series

Comment: @ColinRicardo I am not reassigning t or b anywhere outside of the loop. When I print t and b they are both still 5x3 dataframe with values 1 through 15

Comment: @CrashingWater you're not reassigning `t` or `b` inside the loop either, so you shouldn't expect them to change.

Comment: @ColinRicardo I thought since `hi` takes on both `t` and `b` at one point that it should be modifying them each

Comment: Yes, this will not work. You need to refer to the dataframes in your list by index (not by a temporary value such as `hi`). You can find a SO answer that deals with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370848/3474397)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change elements of a list while iterating over the list that way. Search "changing list elements loop python" for a bunch of good stack overflow questions on why this is the case. My understanding is that "hi" is value-copied, not a reference to the original variable.

If you want to modify elements in a list iteratively, you can try `enumerate()`, or list comprehensions. You might want to create a dictionary of lists and iterate over that, instead of using variable names to keep track of all the lists, as suggested [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).